# If $f(z)$ is continuous in a region G then $|f(z)|$ is also continuous

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

So far I did
For any complex numbers $z_1, z_2$ we have by triangle inequality $$|z_1+z_2|\le |z_1|+|z_2|$$

Now 
\begin{align*}
&z_1|=|z_1-z_2+z_2|\le |z_1-z_2|+|z_2|\\
\Rightarrow\,& |z_1|-|z_2|\le |z_1-z_2|
\end{align*}

Similarly it can be shown that $$-(|z_1|-|z_2|)\le |z_1-z_2|$$

Therefore combining these above inequalities we can write $$\Bigg||z_1|-|z_2|\Bigg|\le |z_1-z_2|\hspace{2cm}(1)$$

Now since $f(z)$ is continuous we have $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0$ such that $$|z_1-z_2|<\delta\Rightarrow |f(z_1)-f(z_2)|<\epsilon$$

Therefore by using $(1)$ we have $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0$ such that $$|z_1-z_2|<\delta\Rightarrow \Bigg||f(z_1)|-|f(z_2)|\Bigg|\le |f(z_1)-f(z_2)|<\epsilon$$

which impies $|f(z)|$ is also continuous.

Am I right? Any suggestions would great. Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks good, but it's probably more direct to prove that $g(z)=|z|$ is continuous, then it follows that $|f(z)| = g(f(z))$ must be continuous as the composition $g \circ f$ of two continuous functions.

Comment: @dxiv Thanks a lot......